# Dynamically adding views to array without using AnyView

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am attempting to create a 'Shortcuts' style interface where you can pick one or more actions from a list and add them to your 'workflow'. This would involve dynamically inserting views into an array. I realise this can be done using `AnyView` but with the performance implications it has this seems like a bad idea.

My initial (perhaps naive) approach was to do the following:

```swift
struct WorkflowView<Action: View>: View {
  
  var actionItems: [Action] = []

  var body: some View {
    ...
  }
}
```

But this causes an issue at the call site since the compiler needs to know the type for the array you are passing in

```swift
  WorkflowView(actionItems: [Text("Hi"), Image(systemImage: "circle")]) // Compiler error as it can't determine the type for the array
```

Is there any way to do this without using AnyView?

Comment: It is not about SwiftUI it is swift static typing, you try to put into array instances of different types. Think instead about using instances of same model type and generate view dynamically, depending on model value. Here is an example of approach https://stackoverflow.com/a/63611331/12299030.

Comment: @Chris: All the Asperi said I say also, plus it is possible to do the thing you are trying to do but it needs deep understanding of SwiftUI protocols, one small help for you, you need ViewBuilder wrapper also you need TupleView and instead of `<Action: View>` you are going work with `<Action1: View, Action2: View, Action3: View, ...>`

Comment: You should watch the Demystifying SwiftUI video from WWDC21